# Позиция текста в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как сделать чтобы текст в `EditText` отображался с левого верхнего угла, а не по середине высоты `EditText`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пропишите `android:gravity="top|left"` у `EditText` в разметке.

Comment: Не работает. Возможно потому, что я отлаживаю на Android 2.3?

Comment: gravity был добавлен с API Level 1, но все же попробуйте на 4,0+

Comment: @KuznetsovSergey, возможно у вас `InstantRun` глючит. Попробуйте его в настройках студии вырубить